# Add an existing origin to a django project and pull the existing repo in it.

Tags: django, git, github, git-branch

I am new to GIT hub version Controlling System.
I am working on a project which i downloaded as zip from GIT hub. It is not a git repository. What i want to do is that I want to make it a git repository and want to pull the existing git repository in it when issuing a git pull command.
I want to create my own Development Branch, develop code on local, push code to github, then do a pull request

Help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have any history of your changes to preserve I think your best bet is to clone the repo normally, and then copy your changes into that repository.  Your question is a bit sparse on details, but something like the following should work

```
git clone <git hub project> <new folder on your system>
# maybe you can use a tag here for the SHA 
git checkout -b my_branch SHA_THAT_REPRESENTS_YOUR_ZIP_DOWNLOAD
cp -r <your existing directory> <your new git repository>
git status # abort if this step doesn't look right 
git add # add all your changed files 
git commit # commit your work
git rebase <main dev branch> # catch up
```

Comment: Yes @Andrew C , I did the same and it is working for me . Thanks